# How to Fix undefined function "createpde"

Tags: matlab, pde

I run a program about partial differential equation in MATLAB, so I used

```
model = createpde();
```

But there's an error:

> Undefined function 'createpde' for input arguments of type 'double'.

I tried to search the solution and based on another forum, I should use `which createpd -all` to determine the path of the function. But when I tried to used that command, I got this error:

> createpde not found

So how can I fix this error?

Comment: You must not have the partial differential equation toolbox. You can check this by looking for it when you type `ver`.

Comment: you're right! then how to have pde toolbox?

Comment: You would have to purchase it from The Mathworks. It is a separate product

Comment: oww i'm sorry i checked it again and i have it

Comment: THen what version of MATLAB are you using? `createpde` was introduced in R2015a

Comment: 2014a sir. So i need to install R2015a? thanks a lot man!